# Newsletter and duplicated questions

Tags: bug, status-completed

While I was browsing the site, I noticed Subscribe to Newsletter button. When I clicked on "show example" (of newsletter) button window poped up and showed me what I guess is this week top questions.
Anyway, I noticed that in newsletter is placed question which is marked as duplicated and closed. Irony is... Above closed question is the very same question asked, but as it was on the site earlier it was considered legimit and the other not (it's about admin asking for password).

My question is... Should the questions which are duplicated be listed in the newsletter? It looks little bit akward, to be honest.

P.S. Can someone, please, add proper tag(s)? I couldn't find suitable one and, unfortunately, I don't have high enough reputation to create one by myself. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for finding this, @Stupid! And, thanks for letting me know about the newsletter - didn't even know there was one, till i read this question... Had to go looking for it... :$

Comment: Hehe, welcome! And I got answer from Jeff itself... Now I'm going to get drunk in that name! :]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good point -- people subscribing to the newsletter are unlikely to hold the 3k rep necessary to cast a reopen vote on closed questions, so there's no reason to show them closed questions.

We'll change this next week, so closed Qs are not sent out in email newsletters.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff! Funny, I hadn't known about the newsletter till now...